# How can I take values from a certain range of cells and copy it to a certain range in the dataframe in Python?

Tags: python

Good Day Everyone!

So got to do something probably a million times in this project which I just don't understand.

For example look at the dataset here:
[image: The Username Column]

What I most specifically need are the first 20 usernames so from index 0:20 and these need to go to the Sponsor column which can be seen here:

[image: The Sponsor Column where I need those Usernames copied on]

What this dataset does is build a genealogy that I'm trying to achieve here.

Kindly help if you can

Comment: Do you need to copy those username to next 20 empty cells of Sponsor Column ?

Comment: YES! That's exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let us know your output

```
u_names = df.Username.values[:20]
for idx, row in df.loc[20:40].iterrows():
    row['MainSponsor'] = u_names[idx]
```

Comment: IndexError: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15

Comment: Try printing those values and check, If its index error it could be that your dataframe length is less than 40, could be only 34